# Google Picker API shows deleted files

Tags: google-drive-api, google-picker

I want to only display in Google Picker view list the files that currently on the drive or if possible only in a specific folder. However, when I try to open the picker, it also displays the files that have been deleted before. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its possible to view trashed files even if you want to with the picker.

Is it possible the files exist in a subfolder you are not aware of? I know I have made that mistake. You might find them if you search your drive.

As far as I know, to see trashed files you would have to use the gapi.client.drive.files.list api. It actually defaults to showing them so you have to exclude them using the query term:

```
      'q' : 'trashed = false'
```